# jQuery mmenu intermittently opening on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, mmenu

I'm trying to figure out why mmenu is sometimes displaying as open when my page loads and other times it doesn't. Even though I'm using wordpress, I'm using the jQuery plugin (not the wordpress plugin). There's nothing that stands out to me about the code I'm using and I'm not getting any errors. What am I missing here? I'm trying to follow the documentation on the site, but nothing is mentioned about this issue.

```
// html markup
<div class="col-md-1 pull-right" id="mobile-nav-link-container">
    <a id="mobile-nav-link" href="#mobile-nav">Menu</a>
</div>

// js
(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {

        var menu = $("nav#mobile-nav");

        menu.mmenu({
            classes: 'mm-light',
            counters: true,
            offCanvas: {
                position: 'right'
            }
        });
        // Make sure that nav items with sub-menus have non-clickable parent links.
        var hasChildren = menu.find(".page_item_has_children");
        var childLink = hasChildren.find('a.mm-next');
        childLink.addClass('mm-fullsubopen');

    });
})(jQuery);

// php for wordpress
<nav id="mobile-nav">
  <?php
    wp_nav_menu(array(
      'theme_location' => 'header-menu',
      'container' => false
    ));
  ?>
</nav>
```

Comment: can you provide demo link? or you can reproduce issue some where.

Comment: I can try to reproduce it on jsfiddle or similar, but I can't link to the site I'm working on right now.

Comment: What is the `id+` in your  <nav>  in php ???

Comment: It was a mistake. when I copy/pasted the code that time it didn't format correctly. So I re-wrote it by hand and didn't notice that I'd done + instead of =. In my project, it's =. I will edit it here as well.

Comment: Hello again, a very long time ago I've maded it work for WP and even wrote on mmenu github account the trick. The author removed it now, I think because he now has made a plugin. I have 2 suggestions for you. 1- In JS , remove `(function ($) {` and change `$(document).ready(function()` TO `jQuery(document).ready(function($)` remove the `(jQuery)` at the end. 2- Look at the author's plugin. Finaly make sure mmenu is in the head and fires before everything else. Hope this helps, SYA.

Comment: That seems to have solved it. Thanks very much. If you want to change your comment into an answer, I'll mark it as accepted.